# Вывод числа в php

Tags: ajax, php

Надо сделать так, чтобы он принимал ответ из name="id" и перенаправлял страницу в новой вкладке: index?id=(то что было введено в поле), это надо сделать на ajax и js

```
      <form action='' method='POST' id='formsearch'>
        <input type='search' name='id' placeholder='| ID пользователя'>
        <button type='button' onClick='search();'>Найти</button>
      </form><br />
```

Comment: Ну, как минимум, $_POST['id']

Comment: @knes, ну это варнингом вроде только грозит, не зная константы php преобразует ее в строку, поэтому здесь не это,

@cnofss, вы плохо понимаете, как все работает. При отдаче странице клиенту работает PHP, а далее никакого PHP уже нет, есть только JS. Поэтому `$x` никогда не примет то значение, которое вы хотите - к тому моменту как это значение будет формироваться, никакой формы еще и в помине нет. А когда вы отправляете POST, то отправляете его на testa.php, а не на ваш index.php. Отсюда и ошибки.

Разделите логику и вьюху - тогда таких проблем не будет

Comment: у вас есть testa.php - делайте там работу с mysql, а результат возвращайте как json. Тогда после выполнения ajax-запроса вы получите массив данных который сможете вставить в любое место на странице

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function search() {
    var id=formsearch.id.value.toString();
    window.location.href='index?id='+id;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action='' method='POST' id='formsearch'>
<input type='search' name='id' placeholder='| ID пользователя'>
<input type='submit' value='Найти'>
</form><br />
```

Обработчик:

```
if($_POST){
header('Location: '.index.php?id=$_POST['id']);
}
```

В индекс.пхп

```
if($_GET['id']){
  Тут выполняем нужный вам код.
}
```

Как-то так, но можно сделать все и проще, если нужно, могу помочь.